# Ошибка “Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства требуется ссылка на объект”

Tags: c#

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
{
    //используем Input.GetAxis для оси Х. метод возвращает значение оси в пределах от -1 до 1.
    //при стандартных настройках проекта 
    //-1 возвращается при нажатии на клавиатуре стрелки влево (или клавиши А),
    //1 возвращается при нажатии на клавиатуре стрелки вправо (или клавиши D)
    float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    //в компоненте анимаций изменяем значение параметра Speed на значение оси Х.
    //приэтом нам нужен модуль значения
    anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(move));

    //обращаемся к компоненту персонажа RigidBody2D. задаем ему скорость по оси Х, 
    //равную значению оси Х умноженное на значение макс. скорости
    Rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

    //если нажали клавишу для перемещения вправо, а персонаж направлен влево
    if (move > 0 && !isFacingRight)
        //отражаем персонажа вправо
        Flip();
    //обратная ситуация. отражаем персонажа влево
    else if (move < 0 && isFacingRight)
        Flip();
}
```

В этой части кода жалуются на вот эту строку "Rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);" и выдаёт "Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства требуется ссылка на объект

Comment: Либо `var adsf = new Rigidbody2D(); asdf.velocity = ...` либо ищете нужный вам объект (в базе или где-то ещё) и ему устанавливайте параметр.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала вам нужно получить ваш RigidBody

```
Rb = GetComponent<RigidBody2d>()
```

В методе Start к примеру. 
И уже потом работать с rb

Comment: теперь он жалуется на RB2D внутри, та же ошибка, что и перед "равно"

Comment: можете показать как сейчас код выглядит  ?

Comment: "RB = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, Rigidbody2D.velocity.x);" 
и добавил вот такие строчки:
RB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
private Rigidbody2D RB;

Comment: Rigidbody2D.velocity.x нужно заменить на аналогичный RB  и ошибки не будет

Comment: именно вот так?(RB = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, RB.velocity,y); @Andrey

Comment: да.Теперь вы  обращаетесь к  твердому телу что висит на вашем объекте

Comment: теперь вылетает другая ошибка (error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Vector2' to `UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D') @Andrey

Comment: потому что rb Типа RigidBody2D, а вы ему присваиваете значение  типа Vector2.

Comment: rb.velocity = new Vector2(....);

Comment: rb.velocity в этом случае тоже типа Vector2. И поэтому проблем не будет.

Comment: вам нужно четко понимать что именно вы делаете. Вам стоит с этим разобраться и почитать больше теории как по c#  так и по Unity. Тогда вы сможете легко разбираться с подобными проблемами.